# Migrate Spring Security configuration for Spring Security 6

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have this Spring Security code which I want to configure for Spring Security 6:

```
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(permittedAntMatchers())
        .permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

    .....

    http.exceptionHandling()....;
  }
```

I get error for `Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'`. Do you know how I can migrate this project properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before upgrading to Spring 6 you can upgrade to Spring security 5.8.x version to prepare for spring security 6. There is migration documentation which will help what things to change. [Preparing for 6.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html).

Spring Security 6 has removed `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class. So you cant use `public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {` method. Instead you need to create `SecurityFilterChain Bean`.

With your code following are the changes required.

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(permittedAntMatchers()).permitAll();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/**")).authenticated();
    
    http.exceptionHandling().....;
    return http.build();
}

RequestMatcher[] permittedAntMatchers() {
    List<RequestMatcher> matchers = new ArrayList<>();
    matchers.add(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/*")); // Sample
    // Add all your matchers
    return matchers.toArray(new RequestMatcher[0]);
}
```